# Applescript - How to run a single bash command from terminal and wait for response before continue?

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript

I have a `modelinfo.sh` file, if I run it in Terminal it echos/saves results to a TXT file.

To execute this file from Terminal I use command:

```
./modelinfo.sh -s C8QH74G6DP11
```

With this command it saves results for given serialnumber: `C8QH74G6DP11`

I need to get reports for 5000 serials, so I think AppleScript might help me?

I have wrote this code with AppleScript:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8TJ14JWDP11") in window 1
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QH74G6DP12") in window 1
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QKGFWSDP13") in window 1
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QKFR5FDP14") in window 1
end tell
```

With this Code above my IP gets Blocked and I get only report for the first serialnumber.

I have also tried:

```
on delay duration
    set endTime to (current date) + duration
    repeat while (current date) is less than endTime
        tell AppleScript to delay duration
    end repeat
end delay
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8TJ14JWDP11") in window 1
    delay 20
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QH74G6DP12") in window 1
    delay 20
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QKGFWSDP13") in window 1
    delay 20
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8QKFR5FDP14") in window 1
end tell
```

But this code doesn't help either..

Last I tried:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s C8TJ14JWDP11") in window 1
end tell
```

This last script I can run as many times as I want and I always gets the report without getting my IP blocked.

It looks like Applescript runs all 4 serials at once even I get IP blocked?
Since I am able to run single check multiple times without getting blocked.

Can anyone please help and point me in right direction?

Is it possible to this with Applescript?
Or can I make a new bash file which runs all my 5000 commands 1 by 1?

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the values into an array rather than calling them individually over and over?

Comment: I am new with Bash/Applescript. Have only used array in PHP. Can you please show a sample of what you mean? Thank you

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you're using Applescript in the first place; it seems everything you're doing is calling a shell script — why not just cut out the Applescript?

Comment: @l'L'l  Yes, all I need to do is to call a shell script 5000 times with different Serials in end. And they should should be called 1 by 1. I thought Applescript was a easy way to do. Please point me in right direction. What shall I use?

Comment: You don't need to call a shell script 5000 times! It would make more sense for the shell script to loop through the array for however many values it has. Post the shell script you're currently calling, and how are the values it uses stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to count the lines and give an indication of progress, replace the code below with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i total
total=$(wc -l <sn.txt)     # count the lines in sn.txt
i=1
while read sn; do
   echo "Fetching $sn ($i of $total)"
   ./modelinfo.sh -s "$sn"
   ((i++))
done < sn.txt
```

**Original Answer**

No idea why anyone would use Applescript for this - it is clearly a simple `bash` script to run from Terminal.

Assume your serial numbers are saved in a file called `sn.txt` like this:

```
C8QH74G6DP11
C8TJ14JWDP11
C8QH74G6DP12
C8QKGFWSDP13
```

You would then save the following in a file called `fetch` in your HOME directory. It reads your serial numbers one at a time and fetches them.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read sn; do
   echo Fetching $sn...
   ./modelinfo.sh -s "$sn"
done < sn.txt
```

Then you would go into Terminal and type the following to make it executable:

```
chmod +x fetch
```

and then you can run it by typing

```
./fetch
```

You start Terminal by holding down `Command` and tapping the Spacebar then typing `Ter` and Spotlight will guess you mean Terminal, then you just hit `Enter` to actually start it.

Comment: Awesome.. Thats a really nice way to do what I want! Can you please share how to COUNT and ECHO total numbers of SN in sn.txt? And also echo which #NR is processing now and how many left? Thanks a MILLION

Comment: Brilliant solution.. Its working exactly as I wanted. Thanks a MILLION for your kind help, this helps me learning alot! I'm on my way :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the common approach in Applescript to use the approach you are trying.

```
property serialList: {"C8TJ14JWDP11", "C8QH74G6DP12", "C8QKGFWSDP13", "C8QKFR5FDP14"}

tell application "Terminal"
repeat with aSerial in serialList
    do script ("./modelinfo.sh -s " & aSerial) in window 1
    delay 20
end
```

This should work. However, the state of the terminal window needs to be finished with the process and ready for the next call for this to work, so a delay of 20 may be too simplistic. Put the above coded inside a try block, to see any error.

```
try
-- above code goes here
on error err
display dialog err
end try
```

Another approach however, is to include the shell commands directly in an Applescript without going through the Terminal app, using

```
do shell script
```

You'll have to post the contents of your modelinfo.sh file to get a sense of that possibility.